# RegExp- How to get words from entire document that match the expression

Tags: c#, regex

Dear StackOverflow Members,

I have a text, lets say very big one (400 words).

I have a regex to find name and surname in that text. Lets say there must be two upper cased words near to each other, and some more rules- doesnt matter really.

Question is:

Is there any way to get that all words from entire text, that match this regex expression ?

Lets say (for example, just to visualize problem): My goal is to list all names and surnames in list...

Comment: You need to provide a sample piece of input and what you expect your output to look like.

Comment: It would be *better* to see what you have and what you want to get...

Comment: Are you looking for `Regex.Matches()`?

Comment: zambonee! Thank you, thats it ....